# How to change colour topbar-submenu border in Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

In the `_settings.scss` file I don't see a variable to change the topbar-submenu border colour.

There is `$topbar-submenu-background` to change the topbar-submenu background colour, but there's no variable for the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it's `$dropdownmenu-border` under *18. Dropdown Menu*.